# Vim and locales

Tags: plugin-airline, encoding

I'm running Vim (9) on Ubuntu both on my local machine and a VPS. I was working on moving my config to the server, where I encountered an error saying:

```
Invalid argument: listchars=tab:~@\ ,trail:~@,extends:#,nbsp:.
```

After a bit of googling, I found an answer to add `:set encoding=utf8` in my `vimrc`, but I figured it might have had to do with the locale and set `export LANG=hu_HU.UTF-8` in my `.zshrc` on both machines.

Now the Vim on my computer is throwing stuff like this on the screen, while the visually shown lines and my actual cursor positions is misaligned:

```
P1+r436f=323536^[\^[P1+r6b75=1b4f41^[\^[P1+r6b64=1b4f42^[\^[P1+r6b72=1b4f43^[\^[P1+r6b6c=1b4f44^[\^[P1+r2332=1b5b313b
```

The issue goes away if I remove all my theme config (notably `vim-airline`). The issue does not happen now on the server, just on the computer. The Vim config on the two machines are the same.

I obviously don't get something about locales and utf-8 in general, and how that interacts with `vim-airline`.

I'm also not sure if I handled the original issue properly (set encoding).

What happening here and how can I fix this?

**edit:** I rolled back my recent changes to my configuration to one that definitely worked properly and the issue persists, so it must have been the locale changes (I can't really think of anything else), but I have no idea what the original settings were and what *should* work with vim ...

**edit2:** For good measure:

```
❯ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Make sure you set the `encoding` very early in your `.vimrc`, otherwise it may invalidate all loaded strings in memory.

Comment: It's the very first line in `~/.vim/vimrc`, so I'm guessing it's not that :(

Comment: I checked an earlier config and it is definitely not a `.vimrc` issue, or at least not directly.

Comment: utf8 should however be the default at least on linux. So if you remove this line, it works again?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to make the slightest difference. Note that on my computer the `Invalid argument` thing was never a problem, the problem is (I'm guessing that is what they are) shell control characters being printed verbatim.

Comment: it might be terminal related. What is your $TERM setting?

Comment: It's `xterm-kitty`

Comment: Hmm it _is_ a terminal issue. It works fine in `contour` and `wezterm`. In `wezterm` I see ghosts of the strange output for a short time, but they kind of disappear under the statusline (wezterm is also much slower to load than contour so maybe that is why).

Comment: Hmm, that is really strange, it definitely worked in kitty before.

Comment: I don't think this is locale related. Also it may also matter if you are running Vim inside tmux/screen

Comment: FWIW: https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/393

Comment: @romainl oh nice, thanks!

Comment: It does seem likely it is/was some kind of race condition, because I can't reproduce it currently, but I'm changing the plugin loading to `Plug 'preservim/tagbar',  { 'on': 'TagbarToggle' }`, which should hopefully resolve it for sure.

Comment: It happens again and not even removing tagbar completely resolves it ... Could be another similar race condition :) This is going to be fun :D